# Poetry trying to install everything from private repository

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to install dependencies both from pypi and a private repo, here's my original `pyproject.toml`, following [the official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories):

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "project_name"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Me <me@gmyself.com>"]

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "private"
url = "https://url/to/private_repo"
secondary = true

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
Flask = "^2.1.2"
private_package = "*"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = "^22.6.0"
mypy = "^0.961

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

However, running `poetry install` results in poetry trying to install every requirement from the private repo, at least that's what I understand from the resulting traceback:

```
❯ poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.2s)

  RepositoryError

  403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://url/to/private_repo/mypy/

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/repositories/legacy_repository.py:393 in _get
      389│             if response.status_code == 404:
      390│                 return
      391│             response.raise_for_status()
      392│         except requests.HTTPError as e:
    → 393│             raise RepositoryError(e)
      394│ 
      395│         if response.status_code in (401, 403):
      396│             self._log(
      397│                 "Authorization error accessing {url}".format(url=url), level="warn"
```

As you can see, it seems that `poetry` is trying to install `mypy` from `https://url/to/private_repo/mypy/`.

So far I have tried to:

- explicitly set the `source` for each dependency in the `pyproject.toml` file (e.g: `mypy = {version = "^0.961", source = "pypi"}`): then the same thing happens with subdependencies
- set the private repository url via the command `poetry config repositories.private https://url/to/private_repo`: does not seem to have any impact
- all possible combinations of the `default` and `secondary` keys for `[[tool.poetry.source]]`: nothing helps
- adding the private dependency with `poetry add private_package --source private`
- adding explicitly a source to official `pypi` and set it as `default`
- I clear the cache when trying something

N.B: the private repo I'm trying to install from does not require any kind of authentication

Experiencing this behaviour with versions:

- 1.1.4
- 1.1.3
- 1.1.2

Comment: poetry first checks if the project is in your `private-pypi` and then checks `public-pypi`. Here the error is mostly because of `403 client error`. check if your credientials at `$HOME/.config/pypoetry/auth.toml` are correct or not.

Comment: But isn't the `secondary = true` option supposed to make `poetry` checks first `public-pypi` ? 
Also, I don't have any credentials because (I know it's bad) the private repo does not require any authent ( I can install from it with `pip install -i https://url/to/private_repo private_package`

Comment: I had the same issue. Is it had been solved?

Comment: @AndreAraujo not really, the poetry team argue that it is expected behaviour. An [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6713) has been open to suggest a modification, but not sure if this is gonna go anywhere

Answer (score 3):

I refer you to https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6713. What I believe you are looking for is how to get poetry to mimic `pip install --extra-index-url`.

I resolved this issue by specifying the priority of my private repository as `supplemental`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = {version = "^2.0.1+cu118", source = "torch"}
onnxruntime = "^1.15.0"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "PyPI"
priority = "default"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "torch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118"
priority = "supplemental"
```

With this setup only the `torch` package will be resolved from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118. All other dependencies (packages torch depends on as well as onnxruntime) will be resolved from PyPI.

Comment: Glad to see the poetry team decided to add this feature :) 
Pull request link if interested: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/6879

Answer (score 0):

You can install the private package by using

> $ poetry add https://url/to/private_repo/[path_to_source_package]

It should automatically add the package to your poetry.toml file. It is the recommended method https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/basic-usage/

Alternatively you can do

> poetry source add package_name https://url/to/private_repo/

https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#secondary-package-sources

Answer (score 0):

The problem when installing the dependencies is due to the `pip install -i` flag, which is why it takes them from the private repository first.

When using the `-i` flag, it will try to install all the dependencies (and also the dependencies of those dependencies) in the specified URL. In your case, it would be the organization's private feed. As it is PyPi by default, it will be overwritten with your private repo and won't do a fallback to PyPi.

The solution for this is to change the flag from `-i` (or `--index-url`) to `--extra-index-url`, which will first take PyPi as a default repository and only look for the rest of the packages in your `--extra-index-url` specified repository (your organization).

For more info, check https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-0

**There is a separate case**, which is using the `--extra-index-url` flag **but** having the dependencies uploaded to your organization's private feed already.

Researching it with [@diegogonzalezfe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20999311/diegogonzalezfe), and taking a look into this pip GitHub issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8606#issuecomment-665547688, we realized it is a security behavior in which the private feed will take over as default over the PyPi ones.

An example of this is: Organization A creates package `deal_with_private_service_X`. A malicious adversary knows that and uploads a package to pip with the same name but infected with malware. Now, if PyPi was taken as a default it could be game over. It is likely that Poetry behavior follows this principle.

Comment: The OP was asking about Poetry, not pip. You have the idea of the --extra-index-url flag right, but when using Poetry you cannot pass that flag to `poetry add`. You have to define the secondary source in pyproject.toml with the priority `supplemental` to get the same behavior from poetry that you'd get with `pip --extra-index-url`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
repository_name = { git = "git@github.com/myorganization/myprivaterepo.git", branch = "master" }
```

if you use https, replace "git@github.com/myorganization/myprivaterepo.git" for `https://oauth2:[mytoken]@github/myorganization/myprivaterepo.git`

Answer (score -1):

Add your private pypi details in the following way.

```
poetry config repositories.<pypiname> <url>
poetry config http-basic.<pypiname> <pypiname> <pypipassword>
```

then check `~/.config/pypoetry/auth.toml` if the creds are correct or not. It should look something similarly like

```
[http-basic]
[http-basic.<pypiname>]
username = "<pypiname>"
password = "<pypipassword>"
```

Comment: The private repo does not require authentication (I can install from it simply with `pip install -i https://url/to/private_repo private_package`).
Am I supposed to still configure it and leave the values blank ?

Comment: Well `poetry` won't let me put blank values

Comment: try configuring just the <url> `poetry config repositories.<pypiname> <url>` and leave the 2nd command. Does that work?

Comment: That's what I tried originally, it's creating an entry in `~/.config/pypoetry/config.toml` but tha'ts all, does not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got the exact same problem and finally figured out that `poetry` was installed and somehow not installed at the same time (I have no idea how or why). From my poetry environment I couldn't see the poetry version `pip show poetry`, so I installed poetry again with `pip install poetry` and now it works. Not only in my current poetry environment but in all of them.